# output_path not working in behat 2.4.0?

Tags: behat, mink

I'm experiencing problems with HTML formatter and the output_path in behat. I'm using cmd:

`behat --format=html --out=output.html --config /www/config/behat.yml test.feature`

Simplified config (**behat.yml**) looks like this:

```
default:
  formatter:
    name:                   html
    parameters:
      output_path:          /www/features/output
```

The problem is that no matter what output_path I set, the **output.html** is always placed inside same directory, where is **behat.yml** (/www/config). Can anybody see what am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot for help!

**UPDATE** Behat v 2.4.3 use the output dir same as current dir (not the same as config), but still `output_path` parameter in behat.yml seems not working.

Answer (score 0):

consider using the command line args and see if the issue still happens

for example:

/bin/behat --config=/pathToYML -f pretty,progress,junit --out path/to/output/file/for/pretty,,path/to/junit/output/file /path/to/behat/features/folder

The command line stuff seems to want all three if you don't specify something it will output to console which is why there are , , between pretty and path

This could hold a clue as to why you are having a problem if the command line wants more than one option by default you might need to configure your yaml for that as well.

Our shell script just feeds the command line what we want dynamically instead of doing guess work with yaml configs. Good luck

Comment: yes, I think I misunderstood the `output_path` in config, as it needs the full path to file, not just dir path. It would be good if I could use reference to cmdline argument for `--out`, but don't know how... Any idea? Something like `output_path:          /www/features/output/%arg%` when calling `behat -f=html --out=test.html`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with behat 2.4.0, this was a known bug that was fixed on version 2.4.3.
Installation method #2 (PHAR) in the [guide](http://docs.behat.org/cookbook/behat_and_mink.html#installing-mink) unfortunately only gives you version 2.4.0 at the time of writting... So in order to fix this you'll have to use the composer method #1.

Hope that helps!